# Not getting any ajax call response in Chrome browser

Tags: ajax

In my application , there is an AJAX call from a .ASPX file to another .ASPX.
In all browsers except in **Google Chrome** it works fine.
In Chrome, **readyState** is not changing from **1** to **2**.

Please help, Thanks in advance..

Comment: There is a number of reasons why Chrome might block an AJAX (HTTP request from within an HTTPS site, a plugin also might also be blocking, e.g. adblocker, etc). Have you checked chrome dev tools (F12) for any errors (network tab, console).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is fixed by adding a **Custom Response Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"** with value * in IIS.